# Why the Objective C method still can be invoked when object was released?

Tags: objective-c

Class definition:

```
#import "MyClass.h"


@implementation MyClass

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)print
{
    NSLog(@"Hello World");

}

@end
```

And main file:

```
MyClass * m = [[MyClass alloc]init];
[m print];

[m release];

[m print];
```

Result:

Hello World

Hello World

Why the 2nd method still invoked when object is released?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Releasing an object simply marks the memory it used as being available to be reused for other purposes. It doesn't overwrite it with zeroes or anything like that. In your example, you haven't created any new objects, so nothing has had a chance to reuse the memory formerly known as "m".

This why it's a common pattern to release an object *and* assign nil to the pointer, to prevent accidental re-use of an invalid object:

```
[m release]
m = nil;
```

Comment: I might comment on this pattern that is discussed controversially. By setting the variable to nil your app does not crash when using it after release which is good, but it can make it harder to track a bug in memory management because it does not crash and so you maybe not know that you have a problem. I personally do not use this pattern because of these problems.

Comment: I use accessor methods religiously, so I can count on the fingers of one hand the number of memory management bugs I've had in the past ten years - and they've been easy to track down, because the relevant code was always nicely encapsulated in a setter method. :-)

Comment: You are right, there are very few examples not to rely on accessor methods. But if you do, then setting to nil is also not necessary. I also have few problems with memory management. For a beginner however I personally think it is better that the app really crashes if something goes wrong than to fail silently. However, setting the variable to nil and using `NSZombiesEnabled` seems to be a good option, too.

Comment: Calling `-release` manually is rarely necessary either. The only time I do so is in `-dealloc`, where it's commonly not recommended to use the setter method, to avoid side effects. I admit though, setting released object pointers to nil is a bit cargo-cultish of me - I once read a fairly convincing argument that it was a good idea to do so, so I've been doing it ever since, despite having never had any huge problems from not doing so before then. :-)

Comment: I think we both agree that getting memory management right is key for writing stable programs. To be honest you seem to be an experienced programmer, even leaving setting to nil out would not really affect you as you obviously understand memory management. I think more than these implementation details is that one understands the reasoning and the underlying concept of object ownership when thinking about memory management.

Comment: These are always the best discussions if both have the same opinion ;-)

Answer (score 1):

That's because the memory for that object still is in place and hasn't been overwritten with garbage yet. Also, the method in question doesn't rely on any other (released) instance variable. In short: it's just pure chance that it worked.

Try setting the environment variable [NSZombieEnabled](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled) and running that again to see that you really just had "luck".

Answer (score 0):

Accessing freed memory is undefined behavior. When you're invoking undefined behavior, anything can happen. This falls under the heading of "anything," so it's a reasonable thing to have happen — so is accessing the wrong object or just crashing, which are also likely outcomes.

Comment: It is basically russian roulette ;-)